# Pinterest pins through HTML/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, pinterest, xmlhttprequest

I Have been using [pins](http://widgets.pinterest.com/v3/pidgets/pins/info/?pin_ids=308074430730953911) to get the information of a pin from pinterest.

The following is the script being used:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getresponse1()
    {
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", "https://widgets.pinterest.com/v3/pidgets/pins/info/?pin_ids="+{Pin ID});
    alert(xmlHttp.status);
    var data=xmlHttp.responseText;
    var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(data);
    var pin_url="www.pinterest.com/pin/"+pin_id+"/";
    var page_name=(jsonResponse["data"][0].pinner.full_name);
    alert(page_name);
    }
    </script>
```

Whenever `XMLHttpRequest()` method is being invoked the status returned is always 0 and the `xmlHttp.responseText` is empty.

But when the [link](https://widgets.pinterest.com/v3/pidgets/pins/info/?pin_ids=308074430730953911) is opened in a browser the response is correct and has all the information of the pin.

**EDIT:**

Tried implementing cross domain too. But yet the status returns 0.
New Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getresponse1()
{
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url="https://widgets.pinterest.com/v3/pidgets/pins/info/?pin_ids=308074430730714588";
      if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
        xhr.open("GET", url, true);    
      } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {

        xhr = new XDomainRequest();
        xhr.open(method, url);

      } else {

        xhr = null;

      }
      alert(xhr.status);
      var data=xhr.responseText;
}
</script>
```

Please let me know where i'm making mistake. Thanks in advance

Note: I'm using Chrome browser

Answer (score 0):

This is an general issue, as you try to do an ajax request to a different site (**cross domain**).

This isn't an new issue at all, I think [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20035319/2633720) it is well explained and this posts provide also some thoughts about possible solutions.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your response. I have implemented a similar code for Google plus Posts, which worked perfectly. I'm not well versed with AJAX. I am using simple Javascript though. I have edited the question and added the new code as suggested in the link you provided. Please have a look into it and let me know where I am making the mistake.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is asynchronous, so your data will only be available from some kind of callback.

```
xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 400) {
        var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    }
};
```